# port are not forwarded, my D-link router to my linux machine

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding, pppoe

i have d-link **(DIR-615)** router with **PPPoE** connection. router **local address** is `192.168.2.1` 
my problem is i can't forward my specific port to my compter.
in router advance setting-> virtual server, i forwarding one specific port to My linux machine which local_address is 192.168.2.9

i listen my **port** using terminal like  ~# **nc -lvp**`port-number`
and  check it using port checker site as well as using my browser like **public-ip:**`port-number`

but it can't work using my public ip-address..
thanks

Comment: Is it just one port that doesn't work, just one device you can't forward to, or is it all ports to all devices?

Comment: i can't understood what yo said. ->paul

Comment: Is it just one port that doesn't work?

Comment: i Found the solution about that.  in Simple language,   i said that the main problem is  `my ISP blocked incoming all port` for dynamic ip [Carrier-grade_NAT]  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)  so i solustion is i want to purchase static ip for that.

Answer (score 0):

Most consumer routers do not support self-loops, meaning connecting from your
local network through the Internet and back into your network.
Evidently, your router is one such. Only rare and very evolved routers
have this capability.

To test the open port, you will need to connect from outside your local network.
For example, connect from your smartphone
(when it is not connected to the router).

Answer (score 0):

i Found the solution about that.  in Simple language,   i said that the main problem is `my ISP blocked incoming all port` for dynamic ip [Carrier-grade_NAT]  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)  so i solution is i should purchase static ip for that.